# parsing URL in String from JSON

Tags: java, json, arrays, jsonexception

1) I've got a JSON file:

```
{
  "serverURI":"http://localhost:8080/PocketUNI_API/serverURLs",
  "newsURI":"http://localhost:8080/gateway/rss/rss.xml",
  "modulesURI":"http://localhost:8080/PocketUNI_API/modules"
}
```

2) I need to get URLs on Java client in String format.

```
String json = jsonReceiver.makeHttpRequest(URL_SERVER, "GET", params);
JSONArray uris = new JSONArray(json);
```

Receiver works fine and json shows the correct string received, but when it goes to parsing with JSONArray it throws an error

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"serverURI":"http:\/\/192.168.0.... of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.
```

Question: How to parse json with URL values?

Comment: why are you trying to convert Object to Array ?

Comment: to loop through the multiple json objects using jsonArray object

Comment: the code you posted above dosnt seems to have an array of jsonobject instead it has a single json object and casting obejct to array will give u jsonexception try to extract a single object

Comment: not `JSONArray` but `JSONObject`. JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a `JSONArray` but a `JSONObject`.

```
JSONObject uris = new JSONObject(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

`json` is a json object not an array, that is why you are getting the error. An array will be wrapped with in `[` and `]`, and objects within `{` and `}`.

```
JSONObject uris = new JSONObject (json);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps!:) Sorry that can't make thumb up, not enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JSONArray` you must use `JSONObject`.

```
JSONObject uris = new JSONObject(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code just replace JSONArray to JSONobject

```
JSONObject uris = new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps!:) Sorry that can't make thumb up, not enough reputation.